# Center collection view cell vertically and horizontally

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

My `CollectionView` takes all the screen, and I need the `Cell` to be centered in the middle of the `CollectionView`, vertically and horizontally.

So, here's how my UI looks like now:

[image]

Each time user loads this controller the number of cells are different. I want to look my cell like a rectangle in the middle of the screen like this:

[image: here]

But I want this without image and the rectangle is turned to the other size, like on my Storyboard. Also, I scroll between cells horizontally.

Comment: Of course, updated my question

Comment: As for the last approach, you mean to add UIView in the center of the Collection Cell? If So, how should I layout my labels inside of this UIView to make them visible? Because they are placed inside of the cell

Comment: I've tried this approach sooner this day. The problem is that when I place all Labels inside this subview (UIView), I can't set any constraints for them, it throws me an interface error, for some reasons. If I drag them onto Cell, constraint work fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151318/discussion-between-rob-and-oleg-blanutsa).